# Limit article to 100 characters. Can't use the_excerpt...

Tags: loop, excerpt

I've been struggling with this for a long time... I want to limit article lenght to 100 characters and after 100 char. limit, add at the end '...' linked to a single post (like wordpress's `<!--more-->` ). But **I can't** use `the_excerpt` becouse it removes formating (ex. `<b>`, `<a>` tags). Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_custom_excerpt( $content, $link ){

   $content = some_function_to_handle_html_tag(substr($content, 0, 100)); // EDIT: need to be customized with a regex for proper output
   $content .= ' <a href="'.$link.'"> more... </a>';

   return $content;
}

function some_function_to_handle_html_tag(){
    //a regex to check last occurance of html opening tag
    //append respective closing tag or strip the tag if broken e.g. '<' or '<something'
}
//for global $post
echo get_custom_excerpt($post->post_content, get_permalink($post->ID)); //print the custom excerpt of 100 characters
```

or

```
//when in loop
echo get_custom_excerpt(get_the_content(), get_permalink(get_the_ID())); //print the custom excerpt of 100 characters
```

**EDIT:**

This could be unstable if some html tag was opened in first 100 character but not closed. I tried to figure out a proper solution (show content without stripping html) but found nothing helpful. But, I have an idea that may help -

1) You may use a regex which will check last occurance of a string which starts with `<` and ends with `>`, then you will have to add a respective closing tag in the end. So, say e.g. if there is tag `<span>`, the `</span>` will need to be added in the end to prevent html layout from breaking.

2) If any occurance like `<` or `<something` occurs, then that should be removed.

Then the above code should work for most of the cases.

Comment: What if you cut the content in the middle of a HTML tag? That could effect the layout of the whole page. It would be great if you could update your solution to solve that possible problem. Multibyte characters might also be a trouble here.

Comment: It worked on the second post not on first one... What I did wrong :O ?

Comment: This code is kinda unstable. I don't know why but after pasting it and refreshing main site it works as I wanted but when I try to edit post and publish it, everything disappears and i only see 'more ...' at the top. :(

Comment: I have edited my answer, however it is not complete but may be helpful. There is actually problem of broken html tag and may be that's why WordPress does not handle html tags in excerpt.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for something [like this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/force_balance_tags)

Comment: Now there is nothing showing up. No article text (like no `the_content`) only 'more...' link. :(